# Concatenate strings without using string functions: Replacing the end of string (null character) gives seg fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, concatenation, string-concatenation

Without using the string.h functions (want to use only the std libs), I wanted to create a new string by concatenating the string provided as an argument to the program. For that, I decided to copy the argument to a new char array of larger size and then replace the end of the string by the characters I want to append.

```
unsigned int argsize=sizeof(argv[1]);
unsigned char *newstr=calloc(argsize+5,1);
newstr=argv[1];    //copied arg string to new string of larger size
newstr[argsize+4]=oname[ns];    //copied the end-of-string null character
newstr[argsize]='.';    //this line gives seg fault
newstr[argsize+1]='X';    //this executes without any error
```

I believe there must be another more secure way of concatenating string without using string functions or by copying and appending char by char into a new char array. I would really want to know such methods. Also, I'm curious to know what is the reason of this segfault.
Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/164258/1176315 and I guess, the compiler is making my null character memory block read only but that's only a guess. I want to know the real reason behind this. 
I will appreciate all your efforts to answer the question. Thanks.
Edit: By using std libs only, I mean to say I don't want to use the strcpy(), strlen(), strcat() etc. functions.

Comment: `sizeof(argv[1]);` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the string.  `sizeof(argv[1]);` is not sensible code.

Comment: `newstr=argv[1]` doesn't copy the string. It overwrites the pointer, causing a memory leak. To copy a string, use the `strcpy` function (or write your own function that's equivalent to `strcpy`).

Comment: Why re-assign pointer `newstr` with `newstr=argv[1];` ?

Comment: @chux Maybe. Though it does give me the correct length of string to use it further in the code. When I print newstr char by char, after copying argv[1], it does print the argv[1] chars. But yeah, this may not be the correct way to do this. What would you suggest to do this? Thanks.
And I didn't think I was reassigning the pointer! Thanks!

Comment: @user3386109 understood! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Without using the string.h functions (want to use only the std libs)

string.h is part of the standard library.

> ```
> unsigned int argsize=sizeof(argv[1]);
> ```

This is wrong. `sizeof` does not tell you the length of a C string, it just tell you how big is the type of its argument. `argv[1]` is a pointer, and `sizeof` will just tell you how big a pointer is on your platform (typically 4 or 8), regardless of the actual content of the string.

If you want to know how long is a C string, you have to examine its characters and count until you find a 0 character (which incidentally is what `strlen` does).

> ```
> newstr=argv[1];    //copied arg string to new string of larger size
> ```

Nope. You just copied the *pointer* stored in `argv[1]` to the variable `newstr`, incidentally losing the pointer that `calloc` returned to you previously, so you have also a memory leak.

To copy a string from a buffer to another you have to copy its characters one by one until you find a 0 character (which incidentally is what `strcpy` does).

All the following lines are thus operating on `argv[1]`, so if you are going out of its original bounds anything can happen.

> I believe there must be another more secure way of concatenating string without using string functions or by copying and appending char by char into a new char array.

C strings are just arrays of characters, everything boils down to copying/reading them one at time. If you don't want to use the provided string functions you'll end up essentially reimplementing them yourself. Mind you, it's a useful exercise, but you have to understand a bit better what C strings are and how pointers work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sizeof(argv[1]) will not return the length of the string you need to count the number of characters in the string using `loops` or using standard library function `strlen()`.second if you want to copy the string you need to use `strcpy()` function.

You supposed to do like this:

```
unsigned int argsize=strlen(argv[1]);  //you can also count the number of character
unsigned char *newstr=calloc((argsize+5),1);
strcpy(newstr,argv[1]);    
newstr[argsize+4]=oname[ns];    
newstr[argsize]='.'; 
newstr[argsize+1]='X';
```